# Issue with multiple gui buttons

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am making a drawing application with the html5 canvas with a custom GUI.  I have a mouse down event listener and a function is called when the mouse is down.  In this function, I get the x and y coordinates of where the mouse is.  I was planning on using and if statement to check if the user is clicking any button, but since there are about 20 buttons on the screen this is definitely  not the most effective way of checking.  I thought about making a button class and object for each button and adding them to an array.  However this approach requires a lot of hardcoding since each button has a unique function and x y position.

What is the best way of going about this?  I appreciate any help or advice!

Answer (score 0):

Why not give them each an id

```
<button id="b1">Button 1</button>
<button id="b2">Button 2</button>
<button id="b3">Button 3</button>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById("b1").addEventListener("click", function(){
   //do something... 
});

document.getElementById("b2").addEventListener("click", function(){
   //do something else... 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

- Give each button an ID and position them using CSS.
- Then use a shared handler which you can bind initially in a loop:

  `var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("buttons"); // or query on parent element
  for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++)
      buttons[i].addEventListener("click", handler);`
- In the handler simply check which button was clicked, then assign a function:

  `function handler() {
      switch(this.id) {  // "this" will be the button that was clicked
         case "btnBrush" : return doSomething1();
         case "btnEraser": return doSomething2();
         ...
      }
  }`